# Navigation Event

Tags: wordpress, navigation

This error came up on wordpress (divi themed) website. With no coding added other than a few plugins. Any ideas how to fix?
A page or script is accessing at least one of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform. Starting in Chrome 101, the amount of information available in the User Agent string will be reduced.
To fix this issue, replace the usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform with feature detection, progressive enhancement, or migrate to navigator.userAgentData.
Note that for performance reasons, only the first access to one of the properties is shown.
1 source
js:1

Thanks

A page or script is accessing at least one of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform. Starting in Chrome 101, the amount of information available in the User Agent string will be reduced.
To fix this issue, replace the usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform with feature detection, progressive enhancement, or migrate to navigator.userAgentData.
Note that for performance reasons, only the first access to one of the properties is shown.
1 source
js:1

Answer (score 0):

It is not an error. It is a warning. It is not so bad. Just letting you know that this functionality will be not available later. If you are not the owner of the plugin which is causing it, the only thing you can do - contact plugin author and ask them to fix it.

If I see something like this on my website, as a dev, I just go and change it directly in code.